# Stored procedure not able to call from Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I'm trying to trigger a stored procedure of MySQL, in MySQL the stored procedure is working fine, but when I try to trigger from Hibernate, its giving exception.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: GetEmployeeDetails
```

Here is my code.

```
//Stored procedure
Query q = session.getNamedQuery("GetEmployeeDetails").setParameter("empId", 10);
List<?> result = q.list();
for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
    Employee e = (Employee)result.get(i);
    System.out.println("Employee Name :"+e.getName());
}
```

My Employee class is.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id
private int id;
private String name;


public Employee() {
}

public Employee(int id, String name) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


}
```

My Stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetEmployeeDetails`(empid  varchar(20))
BEGIN
 select * from employee where id=empid;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define named query for your Employee class.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "GetEmployeeDetails",
        query = "CALL GetEmployeeDetails(:empId)",
        resultClass = Employee.class
    )
})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;


    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me do I need to remove the code from my class?

Comment: Nope, You just need to add @NamedNativeQueries Part. I updated the code Take a Look.

Comment: do I need to use id or empid?

Comment: empId, because you are setting the parameter as empId -  setParameter("empId", 10);

Comment: That is still throwing me the same error :( Hibernate: 
    CALL GetEmployeeDetails(?)
2016-03-22 10:11:37 ERROR EmployeeImpl:203 - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: Then it must be a problem with your store procedure, are you returning the employee in proc ? can you update the question with your store proc ?

Comment: Your procedure is taking empid varchar as argument where as the datatype of id is int as per your Employee class. Also make sure your procedure is returning correct results when executed in database directly.

Comment: The procedure is working fine when I run in workbench. I just need to use the same, where do I need to make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be ok.May be it will be of some other mistakes in mysql side.Else use other alternatives to call the stored procedure like below.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL GetEmployeeDetails(:empId)").addEntity(Employee.class).setParameter("empId", 10);
```

See more at: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/

Comment: @Syed Either you lied or you messed things up.  Calling `createSQLQuery` will not end up with `org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: GetEmployeeDetails` exception

Comment: how could u mapped ur mysql tables with the hibernate model class.You need to map your model class and its fields with corresponding mysql tables and its fields.You can either use xml or can use @Table(name = "employee") annotations to map table with the class and @Column(name=" ") for each fields in the table.

Comment: you can map your stored procedure using a Employee.hbm.xml as specified in the link that i provided in my post.

Comment: ibernate: 
    CALL GetEmployeeDetails(?)
2016-03-22 10:11:37 ERROR EmployeeImpl:203 - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/hibernate-jpa/query/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-hibernate